# JPA/Hibernate ignoring JOIN FETCH with condition on fetched data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I use Spring (no Boot), Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and H2 in-memory DB.
There are 2 entities: `User` and `Post`.
Post has attribute `Set<User> users`.

I have method that should get posts with users that have a name and then print all the posts and all their properties.

When i get posts and try to print users of these posts in the main (testing) class, it ends with `LazyInitializationException`. That is expected.

Using `FetchType.EAGER` works, as well as doing the printing in the service withing transaction or using `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.
However, all these solutions have their drawbacks, so I wanted to created separate method in a repository that would `JOIN FETCH` the users.

I need users that have a name, so my code looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN FETCH p.users u WHERE u.name is not null")
Collection<Post> findAllWithNamedUsers();
```

In this case, the `JOIN FETCH` is probably ignored, because I get the `LazyInitializationException` again:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize 
a collection of role: example.entity.Post.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I tried experimenting with the query (no matter if it does what I need or not)...

`@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN FETCH p.users u WHERE u.is not null")` does not work

`@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN FETCH p.users u")` does not work

`@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.users u")` DOES work

`@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.users u WHERE u.is not null")` does not work

What happens here, why does it behave like this and what can I do to make it working with the condition?

Comment: Your query looks fine, but you'll get a better response if you include the code for your entities and how you are populating the tables

Comment: Please post your entities and the full stack trace.